# Mutate() with multiple conditions from different data frames

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I'd like to create a new variable, namely "InterestRate" based on meeting 2 conditions from 2 data frames. That is, I'd like to "code" in the correct way the following:

```
mutate(X, InterestRate = 
                         if (X$Type.Rate == "FIX", --and--
                            if ( X$maturity > Y$Start & X$maturity < Y$End) --then--
                               left_join(X, Y, by = Rating)) --otherwise--

                          if (X$Type.Rate == "VAR", --and--
                            if ( X$maturity > Y$Start & X$maturity < Y$End), --then--
                               left_join(X, Y, by = Rating)))
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think the more idiomatic way to use `dplyr` is to join in any data you need for calculations and then do those calculations within the new table. So you'd do a `bind_cols` if they line up row-to-row, or `left_join` if their ordering varies, and then all the calcs inside the data frame.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking to do a kind of "non-equi join", which is not currently available in dplyr. Some approaches: 1) If your data isn't very large, you could do a join and then filter/rank to identify the best option with the range you want. 2) use `fuzzyjoin` or 3) data.table to do the non-equi join.